# Can't get distinct records with COL1 and Sorted By COL2

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table as below and there is no primary key in it.

```
COL_Date       Col_Text  Col_Lang
23-July-17     Hello     de
23-July-17     Hello     en
19-July-17     Hello     de
18-July-17     Hello     en
17-July-17     Hello     es
```

I want to fetch the latest row for every language. I can fetch the 2 columns using the below query but it does not include the Col_Text column, Is there a way to do this? Adding the Col_Text to select results in error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col_Lang, MAX(COL_Date) 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY Col_Lang
ORDER BY MAX(COL_Date) DESC, Col_Lang
```

Comment: What DBMS? What error do you get?

Comment: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s" The Col_text is of type Clob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select COL_Date, Col_Text, Col_Lang
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col_lang order by col_date desc) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1;
```

That returns the whole row.  In Oracle, you can also use `keep`:

```
SELECT Col_Lang, MAX(COL_Date),
       MAX(col_text) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY Col_date) as col_text
FROM table1 
GROUP BY Col_Lang
ORDER BY MAX(COL_Date) DESC, Col_Lang;
```

Comment: Why we have added seqnum ? I can see this as an additional column in the result.

Comment: @chitreshsirohi . . . Just select the columns you want in the outer `select`.